# Preference "network.http.accept.default" not available anymore in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I have been using many times the about:config feature of Firefox to modify the Accept HTTP header, by changing the preference network.http.accept.default. Since several months, this preference is no longer available in about:config on my browser (now, version 69). I thought that it may have been a problem that only affects me, due to multiple customisations of Firefox (and the first time I noticed it, other people still had the option in their instance of Firefox).
However, when I was teaching the other day, I realised that none of my students could find the preference.

So I must conclude that probably Mozilla removed this option. However, I cannot find anywhere any trace of such change. So my questions are: did Mozilla really removed this from the last versions of Firefox? If yes, did they provide another way of changing the Accept header? If not, why is it happening to me and my students?

(BTW, I have an extension installed for changing HTTP headers at will, and I know CURL, so my question is not for finding alternative ways of changing the headers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[List of default Accept values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values)

> In Firefox 65 and earlier, this value can be modified using the network.http.accept.default parameter. (source)

So it's likely that the default behavior changed. It doesn't look like they provided alternative means to customize that value.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this [page where the change is documented](https://cat-in-136.github.io/2019/02/diff-between-firefox-660-beta-9-default.html). Too bad, I found this feature very convenient to demonstrate content negotiation without installing any tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Waterfox Classic](https://www.waterfox.net/download/#classic), a clone of Firefox, still does have the "network.http.accept.default" parameter in the preferences accessible via "about:config".